# What is this type of property syntax called: int x=> _x;

Tags: c#

I seemed to have missed the memo on this particular syntax, as I ran across it today and have not seen it before:

```
private readonly PageContext _pageContext;
internal PageContext PageContext => _pageContext;
```

I can guess that it means to return the private value, but what is this type of syntax called, and why would one use it instead of a getter like this?

```
internal PageContext PageContext{get{return _pageContext}};
```

Comment: Use it for simplicity.

Comment: both you mentioned are equal, the former is shorter and that's all really.

Comment: _"why would one use it instead of a getter"_ Maybe this example shows it: `DateTime TimeWhenCalled => DateTime.Now;`. This time will always change even if you look in the debugger. The getter would return the value when it was initialized: `DateTime TimeWhenInitialized { get; } = DateTime.Now;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **expressions bodies** syntax, and it has been introduced in C# 6. You can find more info [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6). As it is stated there:

> Properties and indexers can have getters and setters. Expression
>   bodies can be used to write getter-only properties and indexers where
>   the body of the getter is given by the expression body:

Regarding your second question:

*and why would one use it instead of a getter like this?*

I would use it, in order my code to be more compact. I find it more succint than having to use the curly braces, the return statement, etc.

By the way if you want to declare just a readonly property you could make use also the following syntax, avoiding to declare the backing field, `_pageContext`:

```
internal PageContext PageContext { get; }
```

**Update**

In the example that has been presented by the OP, if we make use of this

```
internal PageContext PageContext { get { return _pageContext } };
```

or the following:

```
internal PageContext PageContext => _pageContext;
```

we would always get the same result. The latter is a syntactic sugar of the first one and it should be preferred since make the code more compact and clear.

In both of these cases `_pageContext` would be initialized in the constructor of the corresponding class, since this is a readonly field and it's value is not declared at the definition of the field:

```
private readonly PageContext _pageContext;
```

On the other hand the following expressions are not the same:

```
DateTime TimeWhenCalled => DateTime.Now;

DateTime TimeWhenInitialized { get; } = DateTime.Now;
```

The first one would return each time that would be called the value of the `DateTime.Now` for this moment. Whereas the second would return always the same value, the value of `DateTime.Now`, when an object of the class that contains this property, is created and the runtime hit this line.

Comment: _"The meaning is exactly the same"_ That's not true and doesn't explain the benefit of thy syntax.I've tried to give an example at [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884169/what-is-this-type-of-property-syntax-called-int-x-x#comment78728139_45884169) above. The difference is, with normal getters you return the value when it was initialized, with expression bodied properties you assign the way how to retrieve the value when the property is called. In this case it makes no difference though.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Since it's a syntactic sugar and the actual IL code generated is exactly the same, I don't see what is wrong with this statement. If I am wrong please let me know. Furthermore, in a certain extent the benefits of a syntax are subjective. I have stated that I found this synatx more succint. This is my personal opinion, which might not be  the same for another person.

Comment: it's same only in this case because OP had no idea how to show a better example(he was asking for). The IL will be different for my two `DateTime` properties that both return `DateTime.Now`:

Expression bodied: `get_TimeWhenCalled:
IL_0000:  call        System.DateTime.get_Now
IL_0005:  ret`         

Pure getter: `get_TimeWhenInitialized:
IL_0000:  ldsfld      UserQuery.<TimeWhenInitialized>k__BackingField
IL_0005:  ret` So the getter returns a backing field whereas the expression always executes `DateTime.Now`

Comment: I understood your point. Thanks. However, the OP despite it didn't show a better example as you say,  the example that we have has not anything regarding the initialization of a field's value. Anyway, I will try to include the example you mentioned in your comment and to make this distinction in my answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter updated. I hope that now is more clear and there isn't any misconception.

Answer (score 0):

It is an Expression Bodied Property.

This syntax is not limited to properties alone, you can find further information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)

It is nothing more than some syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

It is called an [Expression Bodied Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members). You can use it instead of a getter to save typing and write "cleaner" code.

Answer (score -1):

This is called expressions bodies syntax, and it has been introduce in C# 6.0.
If you want provide getter only then you can use it.
It is similar like this
public string Abc{ get{return "this is string";};}